# How to create a message clear command with the amount of messages specified

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
async def delete(ctx, number):
    numbers = int(number)
    await ctx.send("Deleting messages......")
    await discord.Message.delete(numbers)
```

I am new to Discord.py, and I am making a bot that can do basic moderation commands. I was trying to make a clear command that deletes the specified amount of messages, for example `:del 10` would delete 10 messages (Not including the command, so 11 in total). However I kept getting a `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_state'` error. I have no idea how to fix this and tried google, can anyone help? At first I had a while loop after the `await ctx.send("Deleting messages.....")`, it went like:

```
async def delete(ctx, number):
    numbers = int(number)
    max_number == 0 
    await ctx.send("Deleting messages......")
    while max_number <= numbers:
           await discord.Message.delete(numbers)
```

However this was raising the same error as well, and I was not sure if a while loop was even needed as the amount of messages to delete is specified with the `numbers` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use this instead with `ctx.channel.purge` which gets rid of a specific amount of messages in the channel it was executed.

```py
async def clear(ctx, amount: int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit= amount+1)
```